# Generics c#.net

Tags: c#, generics

In the below code "where T : WsgTypes.RouteRestriction", can I add multiple classes so that T can be of only those few classes types which I am interested of

```
    public static T GetDetails<T>(string code) where T : WsgTypes.RouteRestriction
    {
        T details;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(WsgTypes.TicketType))
        {
            details = TicketTypeDetail.GetDetails(code) as T;

        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(WsgTypes.RouteRestriction))
        {
            details = RouteRestrictionDetail.GetDetails(code) as T;

        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("");
        }
        return details;
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: This is not what generic methods were designed for. If you only have a few possibilities, then don't use a generic method in the first place. If there are only three possible types then write three different methods. Generics were designed for those cases where the type is truly generic -- where it can be any of an unbounded number of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inheritance you can have a single class with multiple interfaces.

```
public static T GetDetails<T>(string code) where T : WsgTypes.RouteRestriction, , IComparable
    {
    }
```

Instead you can have an interface and have multiple classes implementing it.

```
public interface IInterface
    {}

    public class Class1: IInterface
    {}

    public class Class2: IInterface
    {}

public static T GetDetails<T>(string code) where T:IInterface
        {
            T instance;
            // ...
            return instance;
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that this isn't a proper use of generics. It would be better if `TicketType` and `RouteRestriction` implemented some `IDetailed`.

Comment: Yep, that's a detailed version of what I described in general :)

Answer (score 4):

No, generic type constraints can only specify a single base-class.

You can specify multiple interfaces, but this is "all of", not "any of".

What you ask is possible with overloading, but not with generics.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't. The usual way is to provide a common interface that all classes you're interested in implement. The problem is that, inside the generic body, the compiler expects a generic type parameter to be unambigous.

Well, or you could take an object as parameter and cast it at your will. But... no. Don't.

Note that instead of `typeof`, you could also use the `is` and `as` operators.

Answer (score 1):

See this article...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

... for more information on constaints. You can add multiple constraints, and you can constrain by some interface or by some base class, but not by a list of arbitrary classes.

Here's an example of multiple constraints (from the above):

```
class Base { }
class Test<T, U>
    where U : struct
    where T : Base, new() { }
```

Comment: That article explains how to use multiple constraints for the same type - i.e. the generic parameter must implement ALL of them.

Comment: Your sample explains different constraints for different type arguments - that's probably not what Miral wants.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try separating them like this:

```
public static T GetDetails<T>(string code) where T : WsgTypes.RouteRestriction, NextClass, AnotherClass, AndSoOn
{
...
}
```